# Asp.net core default route

Tags: c#, .net, routes, asp.net-core

Simplified `Startup` code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "",
        defaults: new { controller = "Main", action = "Index" });
    });
}
```

After running application in Visual Studio 2015 I see in browser "localhost:xxx", but I don't see result of MainController.Index(). Just blank page. What did I miss?

**Update:**

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Update 2:**

The problem comes from exception in dependency injected service to controller and because I forget to use developer exception page site just returned blank page to me. So I'm sorry for incorrect question, but routing is fine in my case.

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if helped you !

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Main", action = "Index" });

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Main}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

These are the two ways of defining default route. You are mixing them. **You need always to define a template.** In the second way you can write the defaults directly in the template.

Comment: Nothing of this helped me. I'm still discovering this issue. After some change whole mvc part stopped working and I can get only static resources like css files and images.

Comment: @KovpaevAlexey https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/routing.html check this url. This is pretty much the basics about routing in .net core.

Comment: The problem comes from exception in dependency injected service to controller and because I forget to use developer exception page site just returned blank page to me. So I'm sorry for incorrect question, but routing is fine in my case.

Comment: @KovpaevAlexey good that everything is working, you can mark the question for correct if you want.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way for me (and without using MVC) was to set the controller to default route using empty [Route("")] custum attribute like so:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("")]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class MainController : ControllerBase
{ ... }
```

with *Startup.Configure*

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

Comment: upvoting for the info on empty routes.  I was having a ton of trouble figuring out how to have a default page load.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be to redirect "/" to another url

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();

            endpoints.MapGet("/", context =>
            {
                return Task.Run(() => context.Response.Redirect("/Account/Login"));
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stumbling over this and wanting to serve static default content (single page app hosted in kestrel or whatever) there is also an extension method [MapFallbackToFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.staticfilesendpointroutebuilderextensions.mapfallbacktofile?view=aspnetcore-6.0) that can be used like this in Program.cs or Startup.cs

```
app.UseEndpoints(
  endpoints =>
  {
    endpoints.MapControllers();  // not needed for this sample
    endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
  });
```

`app` is an `IApplicationBuilder`that you should already have somewhere in your startup code.

Answer (score 0):

For all of you who get blank page set PreserveCompilationContext to true:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

in csproj in vs 2017 or

```
"buildOptions": {   "preserveCompilationContext": true }
```

in project.json

Comment: preserveCompilationContext does a lot of things, maybe you could explain what it is and how it helps for current issue which could have nothing to do with this option ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Startup.cs class, use a convenient Method: **UseMvcWithDefaultRoute()**:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment 
{
   app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
}
```

Can be used to change:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment 
{
   app.UseMvc(routes =>
   {
      routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
   });
}
```

More info in [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2)