# Creating a Login Page in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to create a login page. But it's saying no page found.

I have included this in `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{Controller=LoginController}/{action=Login}");
});
```

The `Login.cshtml` page is in views as `Views/Login/Login.cshtml`
and the controller lies under the Controllers folder with the name `LoginController.cs`
The code for `LoginController.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace AdminControl.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        // POST: LoginController
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

`Login.cshtml`:

```
<form asp-action="Users/Index" class="form-group" id="login-form" method="post" runat="server" style="text-align: center;">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="ID" runat="server" style="text-align: center;"/>
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" runat="server" style="text-align: center;" type="password"/>
</form>

<button class="btn btn-info" form="login-form" value="Submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

What has gone wrong?

Comment: It's a POST action, and your browser uses GET to retrieve the page.

Comment: Why are you doing this like this anyway? MVC Core Identity has this built in.

Comment: @CodeCaster *It's a POST action, and your browser uses GET to retrieve the page* errm, what about the `[HttpPost]` attribute?

Comment: Yes, that [HttpPost] attribute is exactly your problem. When you visit the page in your browser, it issues a GET request. MVC doesn't have an [HttpGet] action to respond with, so it responds with a 404. You need a GET action as well.

Comment: Yes, the browser does a POST when you submit the form (to `Users/Index`, which looks incorrect as well). But to render the form, you need a GET action.

Comment: Pls check my updated answer.

Comment: I think you can take a look at the asp.net core mvc [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-controller?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the error in a pattern: "{Controller=LoginController}/{action=Login}");

```
 pattern: "{Controller=Login}/{action=Login}");
```

But it's better to use a standard default pattern

```
 pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

and redirect from Index action to login controller after checking if user hasn't logined yet

And as  @IsmailDiari noticed,  you should have two actions - one to get login form, another to post login form. But you also need a Model:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
public string Login {get; set;}
public string Password {get; set;}


}
```

After this change controller and views like this:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            var viewModel=new LoginViewModel;
            return View(viewModel);
        }
        // POST: When submitting the login credentials
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Login(LoginViewModel viewModel)
        {
            
        }
```

LoginForm:

```
@model LoginViewModel
  
    @using (Html.BeginForm())  
    {      
      <input class="form-control" asp-for = "Login" name="login" placeholder="Login" runat="server" style            
 ="text-align: center;"/>
     <input class="form-control" asp-for="Password" name="password" placeholder="Password" runat="server" style="text-align: center;" type="password"/>
     <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" />
      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155182/asp-net-core-default-route) to know how to set a default route, you are doing that wrong.
Also you need to provide **Get** action to return the view.
your controller should be like the following

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace AdminControl.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        // Get: Return Login View
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }
        // POST: When submitting the login credentials
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Login(FormCollection collection)
        {
            //1. validation Goes here
            //2. redirection after validation,
            //return View();
        }
   }
}
```

and your cshtml body should be something like this

```html
<body>  
  
    @using (Html.BeginForm())  
    {      
      <input class="form-control" name="id" placeholder="ID" runat="server" style            
 ="text-align: center;"/>
     <input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" runat="server" style="text-align: center;" type="password"/>
     <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" />
      
    }  
</body>
```

you should set **name** attribute to your input so you can find them later in your FormCollection

Comment: However, I would like to note that when I have an Index method (GET) in my code, that method is called, even when Startup.cs defaults to Login

Comment: please see this post to know how to define a default route,
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155182/asp-net-core-default-route)